# TimescaleDb single node kubernetes deployment fails on PodSecurityPolicy

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, timescaledb

I am installing the `0.18.0` TimescaleDb single helm chart. The statefulset comes up but the pods have the following error:

`values.yaml`

```
timescaledb-single:
  image:
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

  service:
    primary:
      labels:
        team: my-team
    replica:
      labels:
        team: my-team

  prometheus:
    enabled: true
  
persistentVolumes:
    wal:
      size: 20G
    data:
      size: 5G

  replicaCount: 3

  serviceAccount:
    create: false  # There's an existing service account already from an earlier install.
    name: my-cluster-timescaledb
```

Error:

```
2022-11-14 18:14:17,077 ERROR: Error creating replica using method pgbackrest: /etc/timescaledb/scripts/pgbackrest_restore.sh exited with code=1
2022-11-14 18:14:17,077 ERROR: failed to bootstrap from leader 'my-cluster-timescaledb-0'
2022-11-14 18:14:27,076 ERROR: Permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/patroni/dcs/kubernetes.py", line 498, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/patroni/dcs/kubernetes.py", line 1088, in touch_member
    ret = self._api.patch_namespaced_pod(self._name, self._namespace, body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/patroni/dcs/kubernetes.py", line 483, in wrapper
    return getattr(self._core_v1_api, func)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/patroni/dcs/kubernetes.py", line 419, in wrapper
    return self._api_client.call_api(method, path, headers, body, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/patroni/dcs/kubernetes.py", line 388, in call_api
    return self._handle_server_response(response, _preload_content)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/patroni/dcs/kubernetes.py", line 218, in _handle_server_response
    raise k8s_client.rest.ApiException(http_resp=response)
patroni.dcs.kubernetes.K8sClient.rest.ApiException: (403)
Reason: Forbidden
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': 'a34c6fd2-a1c3-4cdf-99cf-1288fddf8817', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Mon, 14 Nov 2022 18:14:27 GMT', 'Content-Length': '289'})
HTTP response body: b'{"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"pods \\"my-cluster-timescaledb-1\\" is forbidden: PodSecurityPolicy: unable to validate pod: []","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"name":"my-cluster-timescaledb-1","kind":"pods"},"code":403}\n'
```

I can see that the issue is with the psp, but I can't tell what exact operation is causing the problem, so it's hard to update the psp.

Unless, the error is caused by something else? I see that PATRONI is trying to create some `pgbackup` db?
How do I fix this error?

Comment: Could you post your value file?

Comment: added value file

Answer (score 0):

I've never experienced this error before with timescaledb, as Patroni is returning a 403 error when calling k8s api it is most probably to be a service account issue, id rather delete the old service account and create a new one, so change

```
  serviceAccount:
    create: false  # There's an existing service account already from an earlier install.
    name: my-cluster-timescaledb
```

to:

```
  serviceAccount:
    create: true
```